# Verify Command with discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a verify command where it sends me a dm, and I can check wether they are verified or not, here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
import os
import time
import json

token = os.environ['token']

def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Bot is ready')
   await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(f'My prefix is {get_prefix}'))

@client.command()
async def verify(ctx, message, jj=discord.Member.get_user("270397954773352469")):
  person = message.author
  jj.create_dm()
  await ctx.send('Awaiting Verification, you will recieve a dm when you are verified')
  await jj.send(f'{person} is trying to be verified, do you know him/her?')
```

Comment: I don't see a question, please go through the StackOverflow [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and how to ask questions [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the code not working? Are you facing any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use parameter `message` use `ctx` which you already have to get `ctx.author`. You can get a user by id only with [`client.get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get%20user#discord.Client.get_user) or [`client.fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20user#discord.Client.fetch_user) (and use it inside a function, not as a parameter). Last thing - you usually don't have to use `create_dm()`, but if you want to you can, but remember to correct it to `await jj.create_dm()`.

```py
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
  jj = await client.fetch_user(270397954773352469)
  person = ctx.author
  await ctx.send('Awaiting Verification, you will recieve a dm when you are verified.')
  await jj.send(f'{person.mention} is trying to be verified, do you know him/her?')
```

---

**If you have something like `verified` role (you won't get a message if someone is verified):**

```py
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="verified") # name of your role
    person = ctx.author
    if role in person.roles:
        await ctx.send('You are already verified!')
    else:
        jj = await client.fetch_user(270397954773352469)
        await ctx.send('Awaiting Verification, you will recieve a dm when you are verified.')
        await jj.send(f'{person.mention} is trying to be verified, do you know him/her?')
```